# TinyDB get all IDs in list query

Tags: python, json, tinydb, nosql

I'm using [TinyDB](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tinydb) in my python project. However, in order to make the logic effective, I need to be able to get multiple objects in a query. My preference would be to use a list

```
listOfIDs = ['123', '456']
```

I am using the latest Python version and TinyDB implementation.

I have the following implementation:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('db.json')
myDBQuery= Query()
db.insert({'id': '123', 'name': 'bob'})
db.insert({'id': '456', 'name': 'mary'})
result = db.search(myDBQuery.id.all(['123', '456']))
print(result)
```

However, I keep getting the following as a result:

```
[]
```

I know my implementation is working because when I do the following, I get the expected results:

```
result = db.search((myDBQuery.id == '123') | myDBQuery.id == '456'))
```

Anyone know how to query with a list in TinyDB?

Anyone know how to query with a list in TinyDB?

**EDIT**

For those of you wondering, there isn't a way to do it with the current implementation. My only workaround is to create something like the following

```
def getAllObjectsMatchingId(listOfIds):

tempList = []

for idMember in tempList:
    result = db.search(myDBQuery.id == idMember)
    tempList.append(result)

return tempList
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.all` returns true only if all the elements of the list match the query

`.any` might work instead

```
result = db.search(myDBQuery.id.any(['123', '456']))
```

**EDIT FROM QUESTION OP**: Please see my edit above

Comment: I appreciate the help but that doesn't seem to work either. This is awfully strange as it should be able to accept that due to the documentation: http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: Please take a look in advacnced queries section http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#advanced-queries. It says the field must be a list.

Comment: I might be interpreting incorrectly but it says a User could be and Admin or  User in the query. So it should be able to retrieve all group types matching that query

Comment: In the recap section, it states: Query().field.all(query | list) If given a query, matches all elements where all elements in the list field match the query. If given a list, matches all elements where all elements in the list field are a member of the given list
Query().field.any(query | list) If given a query, matches all elements where at least one element in the list field match the query. If given a list, matches all elements where at least one elements in the list field are a member of the given list

Comment: Also the field must be a list to use 'all' or 'any', here the field it is just integer.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I'm SOL when it comes to saying the SQL equivalent of SELECT * FROM User WHERE Id IN ('123', '456')

Answer (score 0):

This seems the best solution to me:

`db.search(myDBQuery.id.test(lambda x: x in listOfIDs))`

> [test() Matches any document for which the function returns True](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#recap)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still comes accross with this, an alternative to Reinaldo's implementation:

```py
listOfIds = ['1','2','3']
q = Query()
db.search(q.id.one_of(listOfIds))
```

Taken from [Query's API](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#tinydb.queries.Query.one_of):

```
one_of(items: List[Any]) → tinydb.queries.QueryInstance
    Check if the value is contained in a list or generator.
```

You can also negate the query (which was what I needed) to get the items that are NOT in the list:

```py
listOfIds = ['4','5']
q = Query()
db.search(~q.id.one_of(listOfIds))
```